# Node - Parse AWS IP ranges and block

Tags: json, node.js, amazon-web-services

I see that `AWS` posts a `json` file with all their IP ranges [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html#aws-ip-download) (Actual JSON [HERE](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json))

I was thinking of using this `json` file to check against every incoming connection in my node app but firstly I was wondering if it would be far too much overhead to loop through it for every request?

Secondly, I wasn't sure exactly how to go about this, as many IP ranges are formatted differently eg.

```
43.250.192.0/24
46.51.128.0/18
27.0.0.0/22
```

I'm not too sure what them suffix's mean.

Has anyone don something similar?

Comment: There's code available to help with this kind of thing, for example: https://github.com/whitequark/ipaddr.js

Comment: The suffix is the number of bits set to 1 in the subnet mask, from the left, so, e.g. `/18` is `255.255.192.0` (8 bits, 8 bits, 2 bits, 0 bits).  It's called [CIDR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4_subnetting_reference) (pronounced "cider") notation.

Answer (score 3):

Your first concern is correct - it's a lot of overhead to loop through Amazon's IPs for each request. This should be handled at the firewall.

Nevertheless, the `ip_prefix` field Amazon is providing can be used to ensure valid IP addresses exist within that subnet. The [node-ip](https://github.com/indutny/node-ip) module can help with this. It has a `cidrSubnet` function that can be used to test a prefix against a user's IP. See the below coffeescript.

```
ip = require 'node-ip'
amazonIPs = require 'amazonIPs.json'
someUsersIP = '192.168.1.190'

for prefix in amazonIPs.prefix
  if ip.cidrSubnet(prefix).contains(someUsersIP)
    console.log "#{someUsersIP} is within the #{prefix} range"
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution works great, however like you said it's a bit of overhead. The actual requests process very quickly with this taking milliseconds, however a server that normally runs at 3% cpu will run at 30%cpu with this. I guess I need to try and figure out if there's a way to add the ip's to the AWS firewall?

Comment: Yes, you can add them to the AWS firewall. I'm not sure what is going to be sending requests to your node app, but it sounds like it might be another resource of yours deployed in AWS. If so, consider setting up a [Virtural Private Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc). You can configure the firewall only allow requests from within your VPC, ie other apps in your network.

Comment: The requests are from clients, so it needs to be open, however I've experienced some trying to use my API from other AWS servers.